# Postman send value in laravel is null

Tags: laravel, postman

I'm trying to send value in laravel controller using postman but it send null value.

**UserController:**

[image]

**Route:**

[image]

**Postman:**

[image]

There is no problem in get method

Comment: try $request->input('val');

Comment: Have you tried using `Request::header('val');`

Comment: @AchrafKhouadja: It is setting it up on header not body

Comment: sorry didnt realy notice that , your code will propably work

Comment: @AchrafKhouadja: It should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure which one are you accessing since you set the value in header but your variable named input. So, I will just provide both methods since it should be helpful!

There are two different method for accessing the body of the request or accessing the header of the request

#### Accessing the header request

```
$val = $request->header('val');
```

#### Accessing the body request

```
$val = $request->input('val');
```

Comment: ow I saw it. I didn't know that I can Type param in form-data